# How to set root view controller in storyboard animated with navigation controller programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have my login screen how ever i can able to skip that screen and go to home page when I am in the home page I could`d able to get my navigation controller in my home page i have embedded navigation controller with my login page have connectivity via push segue to home page every thing is good but nav bar is not coming in homepage if I try to embedded nav controller in homepage then also its not coming ... my code is

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
     NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

     if (![defaults boolForKey:@"registered"])

     {   NSLog(@"no user register ");
     UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
     ViewController *secondViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginPage"];
     self.window.rootViewController = secondViewController;
     // then set your root view controller

     }

     else

     {   NSLog(@"user is daam sure registered");


     UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] ;
         ;
     ABDB_CAMERAHOME *mainviewcontroller = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CameraHome"];

              self.window.rootViewController = mainviewcontroller;
     }

    return YES;
}
```

is their I am missing constraint about nav controller in program please suggest

Comment: Have you set the top bar to navigation bar in xib also?

Comment: nope i did`t set any bar in my home xib separately but i do give some item on nav bar like cam button.

Comment: In latest Xcode their is a setting for bar visibility check for the navigation bar

Comment: its visible but still not coming i think i have to add some programatically navigation setting for view while i am delegat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User following method to set rootViewController using navigation:

```
[(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

In latest Xcode 6.1 in storyboards their are settings for navigation controller bar visibility. You can tick the "Shows Navigation Bar" for display.

Comment: its already check but still when home view appears navigation bar not initialise with his content i think i have give programatically

Comment: will you tell how add nav controller in app delegate ..i think it would be right if have any better way suggest !

Answer (score 0):

In your appDelegate.h add below property and synthesize in .m

`@property(strong,nonatomic)UINavigationController *navigationController;`

```
@synthesize navigationController;
```

now modify app delegate as below

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (![defaults boolForKey:@"registered"])
    {   NSLog(@"no user register ");
        UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        ViewController *secondViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginPage"];
        self.navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
        // then set your root view controller
    }

    else

    {   NSLog(@"user is daam sure registered");
        UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] ;
        ;
        ABDB_CAMERAHOME *mainviewcontroller = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CameraHome"];
        self.navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:mainviewcontroller];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Once all is set, check your storyboard whether you have mentioned proper xib identifier names over there? Also if you have used any navigation controller there, remove that also. Now clean the project from build setting and re-run.